# JavaScript type error data[i] is undefined - but value is there and it is displayed

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Hi I have very strange situation:

JavaScript debugger writes me an error:

```
TypeError: friends.persons[1] is undefined
```

but when I make this:

```
alert(friends.persons[1].name.firstname);
```

then it displays me the name "Ivan" for example.

friends is a JSON data, coming over Ajax request.

What to do, to remove this error message?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: Aren't you calling it (twice) from other scope where it is not defined? or before the AJAX ends?

Comment: No I am calling it after the success: function( data ) { ....

Comment: Try to console.log the friends object before the line where the error raises. What does it contain?

Comment: use a javascript debugger (firebug or chrome-dev-tools preferably) to break on the error, then examine that line of code.

Comment: Ok i found it. The console.log has helped me to see my error :-)